# Need help aligning model in pose mode

Tags: armature

I'm trying to animate a model with an armature and get it to bend its knees. When I try to do this along the Y-axis, it'll have the model be skewed way to the side when I switch the camera facing the X-axis. I probably have my alignment wrong somewhere, but i'm not sure how to fix it? Here's some pictures of the problem.

[image: Bending along the Y-axis]

[image: Skewed along the X-axis]

I want my model to be perfectly aligned along the X-axis stead of skewed like that. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Make sure all your bones in your armature are set to this transform.

[image]

A few of my bones had -0.00 and for some reason that was throwing my alignment off.